# How to get started with ESAPI out of a servlet container

Tags: esapi

Could anyone give some considerations to get started using the ESAPI on a no-web context?
I came with this little test that validates a string with  DefaultValidator.isValidCreditCard, but I got some web-container dependency errors.

The following method is consumed from a Junit Test:

```
@Override
public ValidationErrorList creditCard(String value) {
    this.value = value;
    ValidationErrorList errorList = new ValidationErrorList();
    try {
        isValid = validator.isValidCreditCard(null, value, false, errorList);
    }catch(Exception ie){
        System.out.println(">>> CCValidator: [ " + value + "] " +  ie.getMessage());
        messages = (ArrayList) errorList.errors();
    }
    return messages;
}
```

This is the error that I get (relevant part) of course I'm not running in a container:

---

```
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load ESAPI.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory: C:\foundation\validation\providers\esapi\ESAPI.properties
Loaded 'ESAPI.properties' properties file
Attempting to load validation.properties via file I/O.
Attempting to load validation.properties as resource file via file I/O.
Found in 'org.owasp.esapi.resources' directory: C:\foundation\validation\providers\esapi\validation.properties
Loaded 'validation.properties' properties file
SecurityConfiguration for Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false
SecurityConfiguration for Encoder.AllowMixedEncoding not found in ESAPI.properties. Using default: false

javax/servlet/ServletRequest
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletRequest
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:74)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.httpUtilities(ESAPI.java:121)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.currentRequest(ESAPI.java:70)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.Log4JLogger.log(Log4JLogger.java:434)
...
```

---

Calls to ESAPI..xxxMethods() also raise dependency errors.

Any advice to get started will be appreciate.

Best,

jose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESAPI has a servlet filter API that requires `javax.servlet.ServletRequest` to be on the classpath.  ESAPI is owned by OWASP -->  "Open Web Application Security Project."  Therefore, ESAPI is designed with web applications in mind.

If you're not writing a web application, then its either a console application or a rich client application.  If you don't expect to use it to connect to the outside world, then the main secure practices you really need to worry about are [ensuring that you always use safely parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet), and that any data passed into your application from a source that IS connected to the outside world is properly escaped.  For that, the only thing you need is [OWASP's encoder project.](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I'll take a look to the encoder project.